# Read from one and write to another one csv file - PHP

Tags: php, excel, csv

I have CSV file:

test2.csv

```
ID  Name    Price
Q4  Quail   400
Q2  Quail   500
Q1  Quail   100
```

I open this file in PHP, check some condition, if the price is bigger or smaller, save new price, and then I want to put it in a new CSV file with php.

This is my code:

```
$file = fopen('test2.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
   if (array_key_exists($line[0], $result)) {
        $oldPrice= 500;
        $oldPriceplus20= $oldPrice +($oldPrice*0.2);
        $oldPriceminus20= $oldPrice -($oldPrice*0.2);
        $newPrice = $line[2];
        print( "The 'first' element is in the array\nOld price is: ".$oldPrice."\nNew price is:".$newPrice."\n");
        print("Old price with +20% is:".$oldPriceplus20."\nOld price with -20% is:".$oldPriceminus20."\n");     
        if ($newPrice <= $oldPriceplus20 && $newPrice >= $oldPriceminus20){
            echo"Take new price\n\n";
        }
        else{
            $line[2] = $oldPrice;
            echo"Take the old price.\n";

        }

    }
    $fp = fopen('write.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($line as $lin) {
        fputcsv($fp, array($lin), ',', ' ');
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
fclose($file);
```

But this is the output that I get:

```
Q1
Quail
100
```

Where I did a mistake? My new CSV file should be almost the same as test2.csv just with new prices if that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the output file and writing each element of the input  file as though it was a line in the file.  This version opens the output file at the start and then just adds each line as you process it...

```
$file = fopen('test2.csv', 'r');
$fp = fopen('write.csv', 'w');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    if (array_key_exists($line[0], $result)) {
        $oldPrice= 500;
        $oldPriceplus20= $oldPrice +($oldPrice*0.2);
        $oldPriceminus20= $oldPrice -($oldPrice*0.2);
        $newPrice = $line[2];
        print( "The 'first' element is in the array\nOld price is: ".$oldPrice."\nNew price is:".$newPrice."\n");
        print("Old price with +20% is:".$oldPriceplus20."\nOld price with -20% is:".$oldPriceminus20."\n");
        if ($newPrice <= $oldPriceplus20 && $newPrice >= $oldPriceminus20){
            echo"Take new price\n\n";
        }
        else{
            $line[2] = $oldPrice;
            echo"Take the old price.\n";

        }

    }
    fputcsv($fp, $line, ',', ' ');
}
fclose($file);
fclose($fp);
```